# replace element in numpy array pending a different element's value

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following numpy array (as an example):

```
my_array = [[3, 7, 0]
            [20, 4, 0]
            [7, 54, 0]]
```

I want to replace the 0's in the 3rd column of each row with a value of 5 only if the first index is odd.
So the expected outcome would be:

```
my_array = [[3, 7, 5]
            [20, 4, 0]
            [7, 54, 5]]
```

I tried numpy.where and numpy.place, but couldn't get the expected results.

Is there an elegant way to do this with numpy functions?

Comment: `np.place(my_array[:,2], my_array[:,0] % 2, 5)`. Please provide valid python examples with the expected type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by indexing as:

```
my_array[my_array[:, 0] % 2 != 0, 2] = 5

# my_array[:, 0] % 2 != 0   --- Boolean shows modifying rows --> [ True False  True]
```